# Performing ADF Test on re-ordered time series

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a weekly time series $T$. I am interested in the stationarity of the monthly data instead. As the length of the time series data is limited, can I perform ADF test on the re-ordered time series $T^{'}$: $$t_0,t_4,t_8,...,t_1,t_5,t_9,...,t_2,t_6,t_{10}...,t_3,t_7,t_{11}...$$
? I have read some literature (cannot remember the source) saying this technique can be used to estimate financial time series volatility without losing data.

Comment: Are you suspecting that the series has unit root at monthly frequency and not at weekly?  If so you might want see literature on *seasonal* unit root tests. Your set up has a problem that if there is a unit root at weekly frequency it will not be distinguished from the monthly one (there is also a problem that 3 points in your series are not from the hypothesized process).

Comment: @Dayne thanks for your reply. Found relatively little literature on HEGY test so would like to know more: my test result is suggesting monthly stationarity but not quarterly, is that possible ?

Comment: it's possible to have unit root at quarterly frequency and not at monthly. But in either case it cannot be considered stationary, as there is a unit root after all.